# How to know when all AJAX calls ended

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

I have an ASP page, which on load fires a bunch of AJAX calls. How can I detect in javascript that all AJAX calls finished? The ajax calls are made using AJAXPRO library.
I need this in order to execute some event.

Thanks,
Adrian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ajaxStop global event](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events):

> - **ajaxStop** (Global Event)
>
> This global event is triggered if there are no more Ajax requests being processed.

Example:

```
 $(document).bind("ajaxStop", function(){
   alert("ajax requests have ended!");
 });
```

Comment: ajaxStop event is fired only for ajax calls made with jquery. I'm using AjaxPro library, any clues how to handle that?

Comment: seems that the only way is to use jQuery for AJAX calls...a lot of work ahead